# Error en la ejecución de código en RStudio: la condición tiene longitud > 1 y sólo el primer elemento será usado

Tags: r, rstudio

Inicialmente había creado un documento .rmd con R, en un sistema windows 10 home 64 bit, por defecto la codificación es ANSI (Spanish_Spain.1252), después de convertir el archivo a otro con codificación UTF-8 lo utilizo con RStudio para generar con knitr un documento .pdf

Tengo que utilizar RStudio para generar la salida porque cuando intento renderizar desde R con `rmarkdown::render()` encuentra al procesar el código dataframes creados desde R con codificación no utf-8.

Estoy ajustando el código para mejorar la salida, y me encuentro cada vez que ejecuto un conjunto de líneas con este error, que se repite varias veces (para este código 4 veces), :

```
la condici�n tiene longitud > 1 y s�lo el primer elemento ser� usado
```

Al ejecutar en R las líneas siguientes, el comportamiento es el esperado, muestra en el explorador por defecto la salida html de la tabla.

```
municipio <- "Murcia"
ejercicio <- "2019" #
columnas <- c("Municipio","Año","Esfuerzo Social","Población","Esfuerzo Social por Habitante","Ranking Esfuerzo Social por Habitante","Esfuerzo Total","Relevancia Esfuerzo Social","Ranking Relevancia Esfuerzo Social")
#formato.tabla <- c("striped", "hover", "condensed", "responsive")
formato.tabla <- c("hover", "condensed", "responsive")

df <- subset(esfuerzolocalsocialcapitales[order(-esfuerzolocalsocialcapitales$'Esfuerzo Social por Habitante'),], Año==ejercicio, columnas)
names(df)[names(df)=="Esfuerzo Social por Habitante"] <- 'EsSoHa'
names(df)[names(df)=="Ranking Esfuerzo Social por Habitante"] <- 'Ranking EsSoHa'
names(df)[names(df)=="Relevancia Esfuerzo Social"] <- 'ReEsSo'
names(df)[names(df)=="Ranking Relevancia Esfuerzo Social"] <- 'Ranking ReEsSo'

df %>%
  mutate ('EsSoHa' = currency(`EsSoHa`, "€", digits=2, format="f", big.mark = ".", decimal.mark = ",")) %>%
  mutate ('ReEsSo' = percent(`ReEsSo`, format="f", digits=2)) %>%
 kable(caption=paste("Esfuerzo Social por Habitante ", ejercicio, " ", ".", "Capitales de provincia." , sep=" "), 
  row.names=F, digits = 2, 
  format.args = list(big.mark = ".", decimal.mark = ",")) %>%
 kable_styling(bootstrap_options = formato.tabla, 
  html_font="\"Trebuchet MS\", verdana, sans-serif", 
  full_width = F, fixed_thead = T) %>%
# kable_classic(lightable_options = c("striped", "hover"), 
#  html_font="\"Trebuchet MS\", verdana, sans-serif", 
#  full_width = F, fixed_thead = T) %>%
 row_spec(0, bold=T, monospace=F, color="white", background="#7B7B7B") %>%
 row_spec(grep(paste("^",municipio,"$",sep=""),df$Municipio), bold=T, color="white", background="#C31A00") %>%
 column_spec(grep("^EsSoHa$",colnames(df)), bold=T) %>%
 footnote(general="Elaboración propia con datos del Ministerio de Hacienda.", general_title = "Nota: ") %>%
 footnote(number=c("EsSoHa : Esfuerzo Social por Habitante : Esfuerzo Social / Habitantes",
  "Ranking EsSoHa : Clasificación de los municipios según el Esfuerzo Social por Habitante",
  "ReEsSo : Relevancia Esfuerzo Social : Esfuerzo Social / Esfuerzo Total",
  "Ranking ReEsSo : Clasificación de los municipios según la Relevancia Esfuerzo Social"))
```

Comment: El error que comentas, no parece venir por el lado del código que estás mostrando. Esta asociado al uso de un `if` haciendo una comparación con un vector de más de un elemento, por ejemplo: `if ( 1 == 1:2) print("Si")`, te lo comento para que lo investigues, por que dudo que de la pregunta y del código podamos sacar alguna conclusión.

Comment: Gracias por responder @Patricio Moracho. Sólo ejecuto en RStudio esas líneas que he mostrado. Lo he planteado por si alguien se ha encontrado con este problema que no tiene, a priori, explicación.

Comment: ... Y sin embargo, puedo desde RStudio ejecutar knitr/knitr to HTML, procesando el archivo sin errores.

Comment: Es decir, ejecutas knitr con el archivo completo y funciona bien, pero si ejecutas el "chunk" que muestras te da error? Si es así ten en cuenta que por lo general los chunks dependen de otros que se ejecutaron antes, por ejemplo, en tu código referencias a `esfuerzolocalsocialcapitales`, este objeto lo has cargado previamente y tiene el estado que requiere este "chunk"?

Answer (score 0):

Espero que pueda ayudar a la comunidad, en este caso, el inesperado comportamiento se ha solucionado cambiando la configuración en "Edit the R markdown format options for the current file", seleccionando **"Chunk Output in Console"**, anteriormente estaba establecida en "Chunk Output Inline". Opciones disponibles cuando se abre un archivo RMarkDown .rmd