# Error al ejecutar rmarkdown::render() - Sistema windows 10 64 bit - spanish.España

Tags: r, r-markdown

Estoy teniendo muchos problemas para poder tener una instalación operativa de R, mi propósito es poder generar un documento reproducible. Esta es una cuestión relacionada con esta otra pregunta anterior [(enlace)](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/455262/error-en-la-ejecuci%C3%B3n-de-c%C3%B3digo-en-rstudio-la-condici%C3%B3n-tiene-longitud-1-y-s%C3%B3). No puedo abrir documentos utf8 en R. Mi sistema es windows 10 64 bit. El código funciona bien, el problema viene cuando intento renderizar.

Cuando ejecuto `rmarkdown::render()` para generar la salida de un archivo .rmd directamente desde R obtengo los siguientes errores:

```sh
> rmarkdown::render("esfuerzo local social EELL-ORIGINAL.rmd", "html_document")


processing file: esfuerzo-local-social-EELL-ORIGINAL.rmd

  |                                                                            
  |                                                                      |   0%
  |                                                                            
  |...                                                                   |   4%
  ordinary text without R code


  |                                                                            
  |......                                                                |   8%
label: unnamed-chunk-1 (with options) 
List of 1
 $ include: logi FALSE

Quitting from lines 16-175 (esfuerzo-local-social-EELL-ORIGINAL.rmd) 
Error in parse(text = x, srcfile = src) : <text>:44:1: inesperado '<'
43: tipo <- "esfuerzo"
44: <
    ^
Además: Warning messages:
1: In readLines(con, warn = FALSE) :
  entrada inválida encontrada en la conexión de entrada 'esfuerzo-local-social-EELL-ORIGINAL.rmd'
2: In xfun::read_utf8(input) :
  The file esfuerzo-local-social-EELL-ORIGINAL.rmd is not encoded in UTF-8. These lines contain invalid UTF-8 characters: 3, 21, 29, 35, 36, 38, ...
```

Los valores de mi sesión son estos:

```sh
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.0.5 (2021-03-31)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19043)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Spanish_Spain.1252  LC_CTYPE=Spanish_Spain.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=Spanish_Spain.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                  
[5] LC_TIME=Spanish_Spain.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] bookdown_0.22     prettydoc_0.4.1   htmlwidgets_1.5.3 jsonlite_1.7.2   
 [5] highcharter_0.8.2 plotly_4.9.3      formattable_0.2.1 kableExtra_1.3.4 
 [9] DT_0.18           tinytex_0.31      knitr_1.33        rmarkdown_2.8    
[13] forcats_0.5.1     stringr_1.4.0     dplyr_1.0.6       purrr_0.3.4      
[17] readr_1.4.0       tidyr_1.1.3       tibble_3.1.2      ggplot2_3.3.3    
[21] tidyverse_1.3.1  

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] httr_1.4.2        sass_0.4.0        viridisLite_0.4.0 modelr_0.1.8     
 [5] bslib_0.2.5.1     assertthat_0.2.1  TTR_0.24.2        cellranger_1.1.0 
 [9] yaml_2.2.1        pillar_1.6.1      backports_1.2.1   lattice_0.20-44  
[13] glue_1.4.2        rlist_0.4.6.1     digest_0.6.27     rvest_1.0.0      
[17] colorspace_2.0-1  htmltools_0.5.1.1 pkgconfig_2.0.3   broom_0.7.6      
[21] haven_2.4.1       scales_1.1.1      webshot_0.5.2     svglite_2.0.0    
[25] generics_0.1.0    ellipsis_0.3.2    withr_2.4.2       lazyeval_0.2.2   
[29] cli_2.5.0         quantmod_0.4.18   magrittr_2.0.1    crayon_1.4.1     
[33] readxl_1.3.1      evaluate_0.14     ps_1.6.0          fs_1.5.0         
[37] fansi_0.4.2       xts_0.12.1        xml2_1.3.2        tools_4.0.5      
[41] data.table_1.14.0 hms_1.1.0         lifecycle_1.0.0   munsell_0.5.0    
[45] reprex_2.0.0      jquerylib_0.1.4   compiler_4.0.5    systemfonts_1.0.2
[49] rlang_0.4.11      grid_4.0.5        rstudioapi_0.13   igraph_1.2.6     
[53] gtable_0.3.0      DBI_1.1.1         curl_4.3.1        R6_2.5.0         
[57] zoo_1.8-9         lubridate_1.7.10  utf8_1.2.1        stringi_1.6.2    
[61] Rcpp_1.0.6        vctrs_0.3.8       dbplyr_2.1.1      tidyselect_1.1.1 
[65] xfun_0.23        
>
```

Comment: ¿La generación la haces desde R o desde Rstudio? lamentablemente estos errores son difíciles de resolver desde este lado del monitor, por que básicamente requiere hacer debuging, cosa que únicamente podrías hacer tu. Lo interesante del error es que te da la linea y columna bastante aproximada en dónde esta el problema, en tu caso linea 44, columna 1, el error pareciera ser la asignación `tipo <- "esfuerzo"`, borra esta línea y vuelvela a escribir y a probar.

Comment: Por otro lado también te dice que tu Rmd: `is not encoded in UTF-8` , lo cual seguramente es así. Prueba volver a abrir el archivo con Rstudio y especificar la codificación nuevamente y salvarlo. Otra estrategia, arranca con un Rmd totalmente en blanco, salvado como utf-8 y empieza de a poco a copiar el contenido y a probar cada "chunk".

Comment: Gracias por responder @Patricio Moracho, esta ejecución está hecha desde la RGui de R sobre una versión ANSI de un archivo .rmd. Esa línea 44 tiene este código: ```ámbito <- "local"```

Comment: Cuando utilizo RStudio sobre la versión UTF8 de ese archivo puedo renderizar utilizando knitr/knitr to PDF ó knitr/knitr to HTML, en este caso, con la versión UTF8 tengo problemas para ejecutar partes de los fragmentos de código como describía en otra cuestión que he enlazado en esta pregunta.

Comment: Probaste hacer `rmarkdown::render("esfuerzo local social EELL-ORIGINAL.rmd", "html_document", encoding="UTF-8")`?

Comment: Acabo de hacerlo, la salida de la consola es la misma, idéntica. El problema es justamente ese, el archivo no es UTF-8

Comment: ¿No debería indicar la codificación del archivo, que es ANSI?, ¿Cómo debería especificarla?

Comment: Depende, si el archivo Rmd es efectivamente utf-8 y se usan códigos utf-8 calculo que no. Fijate con `encoding="native"`

Comment: El archivo que estoy procesando es ANSI, y con ```encoding="native"``` el error es el mismo

Comment: Prueba hacer lo que te decía en uno de mis anteriores comentarios, empieza con un Rmd totalmente en blanco y empieza a pasarle el código de a poco u Rmd original y vas probando , cada parte que copias la vas probando renderizar. O bien llegamos realmente a ver dónde está el problema o terminas con un Rmd que si funcione